# Converting rails task to rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have this file in my models/ folder:

```
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'nokogiri'
  require 'open-uri'

  has_many :user_shows
  has_many :users, through: :user_shows

  def self.update_all_screenings
    Show.all.each do |show|
        show.update_attribute(:next_screening, Show.update_next_screening(show.url))
    end
  end

  def self.update_next_screening(url)
    nextep = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    ## Finds the title of the show and extracts the date of the show and converts to string ##
    begin

        title = nextep.at_css('h1').text
        date = nextep.at_css('.next_episode .highlight_date').text[/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/]
        date = date.to_s

    ## Because if it airs today it won't have a date rather a time this checks whether or not 
    ## there is a date. If there is it will remain, if not it will insert todays date
    ## plus get the time that the show is airing    
        if date =~ /\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/
            showtime = DateTime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
        else
            date = DateTime.now.strftime("%D")
            time = nextep.at_css('.next_episode .highlight_date').text[/\dPM|\dAM/]
            time = time.to_s
            showtime = date + " " + time
            showtime = DateTime.strptime(showtime, "%m/%d/%y %l%p")

        end

        return showtime

    rescue
        return nil
    end
  end
end
```

However, when I run

```
Show.update_all_screenings
```

It takes ages to do. I currently have a very similar script that is a rake file that has to do twice the amount of scraping and manages to do it in about 10 minute where as this one will take 8 hours as is. So I was wondering how I would go about converting this file to a rake task? The whole app I'm building depends on this being able to do it in at most 1 hours.

Here is the other script for reference:

```
require 'mechanize'

namespace :show  do

  desc "add tv shows from web into database"
  task :scrape => :environment do
    puts 'scraping...'

    Show.delete_all

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.get 'http://www.tv.com/shows/sort/a_z/'
agent.page.search('//div[@class="alphabet"]//li[not(contains(@class, "selected"))]/a').each do |letter_link|
  agent.get letter_link[:href]
  letter = letter_link.text.upcase
  agent.page.search('//li[@class="show"]/a').map do |show_link| 
    Show.create(title: show_link.text, url:'http://tv.com' + show_link[:href].to_s + 'episodes/')
  end
  while next_page_link = agent.page.at('//div[@class="_pagination"]//a[@class="next"]') do
    agent.get next_page_link[:href]
    agent.page.search('//li[@class="show"]/a').map do |show_link|
      Show.create(title: show_link.text, url:'http://tv.com' + show_link[:href].to_s + 'episodes/')
  end
  end
end

end
end
```

Comment: Try delayed_jobs https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job. Its easy to implement and your method will be run in background

Comment: hey @SachinPrasad will this speed it up or merely place delay when this job will complete?

Comment: It will simply run that method in the background.Delayed job will make that method asynchronous and therefore you don't have to wait for that method to complete.

Comment: @SachinPrasad ahh ok. I was planning on using this for when I had it set up. However, i need this script to run everyday in 1 hour, will doing the delayed job ensure this?

Comment: @HarryLucas I don't know if merely turning this into rake task is the way to speed it up. You can put time outputs at various places to determine which operation is taking so long.

Comment: @HarryLucas If you want to run daily, try this scheduler https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler

Comment: Rake versus non rake won't be why this one is slower.  If you showed the other script the difference between them might become apparent

Comment: @FrederickCheung Hey frederick, I added the other script as well. This one here has to get the show title and the url, which is then passed into the first script which only has to get the date of the next screening.

Comment: Why don't you simply create a task which calls `Show.update_all_screenings`?

Comment: @UriAgassi will that speed it up? Because when I run Show.update_all_screenings in the console it takes about 8 hours presently

Comment: Rake doesn't do any magic - it simply a framework which enables you to run ruby scripts. I'll be surprised if it runs any faster.

Comment: You might want to look at running the different `update_next_screening` _concurrently_, since I believe most of the time spent is waiting for the HTTP calls to return.

Comment: @UriAgassi how would i do that? Sorry I am new to all this and trying to just get a grasp on it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rake is no magic bullet - it will not run your code any faster.

What you *could* do is run your code more efficiently. The main time-consumer in your code is iteratively calling `open(url)`. If you could read all the urls *concurrently*, the whole process should take fraction of the time it takes now.

You could use [`typhoeus`](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) gem (or some other gem) to handle this for you.

**--Danger! Untested code ahead!--**

I have no experience using this gem, but your code could look something like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'typhoeus'

class Show < ActiveRecord::Base


  has_many :user_shows
  has_many :users, through: :user_shows

  def self.update_all_screenings
    hydra = Typhoeus::Hydra.hydra
    Show.all.each do |show|
      request = Typhoeus::Request.new(show.url, followlocation: true)
      request.on_complete do |response|
        show.update_attribute(:next_screening, Show.update_next_screening(response.body))
      end
      hydra.queue(request)
    end
    hydra.run
  end

  def self.update_next_screening(body)
    nextep = Nokogiri::HTML(body)
    ## Finds the title of the show and extracts the date of the show and converts to string ##
    begin

        title = nextep.at_css('h1').text
        date = nextep.at_css('.next_episode .highlight_date').text[/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/]
        date = date.to_s

    ## Because if it airs today it won't have a date rather a time this checks whether or not 
    ## there is a date. If there is it will remain, if not it will insert todays date
    ## plus get the time that the show is airing    
        if date =~ /\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/
            showtime = DateTime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
        else
            date = DateTime.now.strftime("%D")
            time = nextep.at_css('.next_episode .highlight_date').text[/\dPM|\dAM/]
            time = time.to_s
            showtime = date + " " + time
            showtime = DateTime.strptime(showtime, "%m/%d/%y %l%p")

        end

        return showtime

    rescue
        return nil
    end
  end
end
```

The above should collect all the requests in one queue, and run them concurrently, acting on any response as it comes.

Comment: Thanks for the time you put into this! I gave it a shot but seems to be returning on every line:
`performed EASY url=response_code=301`

Comment: @HarryLucas - try `request = Typhoeus::Request.new(show.url, followlocation: true)` (I've updated the post - should follow redirects)